# Tensor categories with integer rank

Tags: braided-tensor-categories, super-algebra

I wonder the state of the following conjecture in "Deformation theory, Kontsevich, Soibelman":

Conjecture 3.3.5. Rigid [abelian symmetric] tensor categories [over an algebraically closed field $k$] with ranks in $\mathbb{Z}$ can be of two types:
comodules over commutative Hopf algebras or comodules over supercommutative
Hopf algebras.

Deligne's result gives the answer for the case $\mathrm{char}(k)=0$ and nonnegative ranks: comodules over a commutative Hopf algebra.

Comment: What does "tensor" mean here?  Symmetric? Braided? Neither?  For symmetric Deligne has a great result.